# Is Google Location service experiencing issues right now?

Tags: dictionary, location

I operate a directory which NEEDS Google location API to work correctly.

eg :
search bar at :
https://www.purelocal.com.au/google-seo

Type location >> it populates
However , today it's only populating results SOME OF THE TIME and it's very frustrating.

Is Google have intermittent issues, the code is the same as it has always been...

Answer (score 0):

No it isn't experiencing issues right now. I don't know what's wrong with your API.